# How do I make and upload a package for my game?

Tags: application-development, packaging

I developed a game using the C programming language with SDL for graphics.

Now, I just have a folder of the project (with project files). But I don't know how to make a package of this game to upload it.

Comment: please add to your question - where do you want to upload your game to? What "package" are you trying to produce - e.g. a debian package compiled into a PPA on launchpad, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use check install

```
apt-get install checkinstall 

checkinstall -D make install
```

See here for further information:

http://www.falkotimme.com/howtos/checkinstall/

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to build a Debian package (.deb) and submit it for inclusion in the Debian or Ubuntu software repositories. Creating a package can be a complex process; detailed instructions are available on the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/) [here](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html).